# How to specify OpenAPI validation for CRD

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm currently writing a kubernetes controller, using kubernetes go-client.

I've managed to generate the OpenAPI spec for the resources managed by the controller (by running `openapi-gen` and annotating types with `+k8s:openapi-gen=true`).

I also want to generate validators like a maximum length or regex but I don't find any resource about how to do it.

Here is my `types.go`

```
package v1

import (
    meta "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

// +genclient
// +k8s:openapi-gen=true
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object
// +resource:path=project

type Project struct {
    meta.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    meta.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Domain string `json:"domain"`
}

// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object

type ProjectList struct {
    meta.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    meta.ListMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Items         []Project `json:"items"`
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to generate the OpenAPI spec using `openapi-gen` and include in the spec the following validation for the `Domain`: regex `[a-z]+` and maximum length of `18`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the crd.yaml file using openAPIV3Schema, as it is compulsory to add structural schema to prevent sending of malicious data to the API server
The solution to your question is to add the below fields in spec part of your yaml:

```
domain:
    type: string
    maxLength: 18                          
    pattern: "[a-z]+"
```

for more information you can read this article:=> [crd-schema](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/06/20/crd-structural-schema/)